# hibernate.cfg.xml not found (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I started using Hibernate today and tested a simple example but I'm getting the error: hibernate.cfg.xml not found.
I putted the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the src folder and here is its content:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-configuration>

  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="connection.username">test</property>
    <property name="connection.password">test</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping resource="com/mycompany/model/Product.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And I putted the HibernateUtil.java file under util folder (src/util) and here is its content

```
    package util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cgf.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

I also have the Jars added to the build path.

My class Test.java :

```
    import ...


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ProductDao pd = new ProductDao();

        try {

            Product p = new Product("PC", 1000L);

            pd.add(p);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

The add method :

public void add(Product p) {

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(p);
tx.commit();
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `src->util` folder, and try again.

Comment: Which building tool you are using like Gradle, Ant, Maven

Comment: I did it but still the same problem.

Comment: I'm not using any tool.

Answer (score 0):

If using maven try putting it in

```
/src/main/resources
```

If using simple eclipse project (without maven), put it in project root directory (not in the src)
[image]

Also you misspelled the name of the file in the source

```
return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cgf.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

it must be

```
hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Comment: That's what I did, It's in the src folder

Comment: No I'm not using maven

Comment: see the picture above

Comment: Still the same problem ... !

Comment: Should I add it to the build path or something like that ?

Comment: I'm using also spring in my project. Should I add any modifications to my spring xml configuration files ??

Comment: I just noticed you misspelled the name of the file: you wrote hibernate.cgf.xml, it must be hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Ok thank you, but now I have another problem : could not instantiate cacheprovider ...

Comment: If I comment the line     <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>      the application works fine. But I don't know if it is important to keep it

Comment: this line presense, will disable the second level cache

Answer (score 0):

If its a Maven project just add cfg.xml file in /src/main/resources in eclips